# Excel put "pic:name of photo" instead of photo

Tags: excel, phpexcel

I have problem with Excel.

When I insert a picture into Excel, it won't load it but writes the name of the picture, for example "pic:name of photo".

I create an offer through the program, it does everything normally, but the image will not be displayed.

Can anyone help me if they know the solution?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNZ6n.png)

I tried od version 365, 2019, 2016 and 2013. Same problem is with all versions.
Same problem is with .jpg (.jpeg) and .png.

Comment: Can you describe exactly how you are trying to insert the image? Do you just `ctrl + c` the image file and `ctrl + v` in excel?